# TabControl Editor(TextBox) - TreeView Issue

Tags: c#

I'm using C# ICSharpCode.TextEditor and I'm having a slight issue with, when I double click a method on the side in my TreeView box, the text should show up where you're selecting, not at the end of the line.

Here is my code:

```
private void solutionBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextEditorControl editor = ActiveEditor;
    if (solutionBox.SelectedNode.Text == "AddAura")
    {
        editor.Text += "Add()";
    }
}
```

Now that would go to the end of my custom code in the textbox editor:

```
 function Hello(pThis)
     pThis:
 endAdd()
```

So, what I want is when you're beside of 'pThis' and when you double click 'Add()', it will show up beside of 'pThis' & not trying to find the end of the line in the TextBox.

I know '+=' is causing it, but I'd like some more options from other people.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding you.. but does editor.Text have an Append() method..?

Comment: what was your fix just out of curiousity

Comment: `private void solutionBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextEditorControl editor = ActiveEditor;
            var text = "";
            var p = editor.ActiveTextAreaControl.TextArea;
            var index = 0;
            if (solutionBox.SelectedNode.Text.Contains("AddThisTest"))
            {
                text = "AddThisTest";
                index = p.Caret.Offset;
                editor.Text = editor.Text.Insert(index, text);
                return;
            }
        }`